# SLES 11 doesn't boot after RAID controller replacement

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, raid, suse

I need to fix a server (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server) that stopped booting correctly after a piece of hardware, responsible for RAID, got damaged and replaced.

The booting process was getting stuck on this message:
`Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360{...}-part1`

I tried to find a live iso of SLES 11 to run rescue system but could only find from 12 to 15. So I downloaded version 15 and I run a rescue system from there.

From this I could see that the fstab was incorrect because the scsi ids found here (the same in the error) were different from what were in /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-.....

From what I could find looking to fix this issue, If I changed manually the fstab to the correct IDs, or the partition names (sda, sdb, ...) it should fix the issue. So I changed to the partition names (should I put only the disk ids here instead?) and did something very wrong when following a guide on the web. After I changed fstab I should run `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` However, because I was using a live Usb with SLE 15, grub was not available and only grub2. So I run grub2-install instead...... which made it install grub2 alongside grub legacy..... Now when I try to boot I get a grub error: `Welcome to GRUB! error: disk 'hd1,msdos1' not found. Entering rescue mode...`

So now, I'm not sure where the problem is. Is it because I have two grubs? (I'm assuming so) If so, my plan is to remove grub2 and run this [tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) using a ubuntu live pen. But how do I remove grub2??

Or is the problem somewhere else?

[image]
This is the fstab after I changed it to use /dev/sdx instead of /disk/by-id/

Please help Unix gurus

--
Old fstab
[image]

To get the partitions correspond to the ids I checked blkid (there could be a margin of error here but as I was able to browse the partitions with a ubuntu live usb I think they are correct....)
[image]

Using chroot to check grub config files:
[image]

**Update**:

running mkinitrd gave the error:
`Root device(/dev/sda1) not found`
(the same goes if I change all the references from sdX to by-id, showing the same error with the partition id)

Running `yast bootloader` makes console not update anymore. Even after pressing ctrl+c. However, it is still getting input since I typed reboot and it worked.

Comment: In the grub.cfg (I'm not sure about SLES 11) try to replace hd1 with hd0. Because of the rescue system your system is aware of two disks and possibly writes the wrong configuration, so when you exit the rescue system SLES is not aware of hd1. I believe it should be in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and/or `/boot/grub/device.map`.

Comment: under /boot I only see grub2, and inside that grub2 folder.... there is nothing

Comment: are you in the `chroot` environment?

Comment: I logged in as root in the rescue system.

Comment: Please also show the original `fstab`. Make sure we can see what partitions correspond to each other. (Why do you hide the mount points?) You seem to have much more partitions than listed in `fstab`. How did you find out which partitions like `sda1` etc. correspond to the ID-based partitions? Maybe you should check all partitions on all disks to find out the correct mount points. Add details about the RAID controller, disks, RAID configuration. Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification instead of writing comments.

Comment: If possible copy&paste information as text instead of showing screenshots.

Comment: Logging into the rescue system is not enough, you need to chroot in order to rewrite the grub configuration.

Comment: Hmm sorry but I don't think I could copy text from the server... Is there a way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Using chroot I can see the grub config files. I only see reference to hd0 on those files and not hd1 like in the grub boot error (part of the issue?) and also, the disk ids on this config files are the old ids.

Comment: Update the disk IDs and rewrite the grub config.

Comment: Update the disk IDs on grub.conf and menu.lst? And should I change hd0 to hd1?

Comment: The disk IDs need to be correct in all relevant places (fstab, grub, etc.), the update of grub (is it `mkinitrd`?) should reflect that. You could also try to run `yast bootloader` in the chroot env and see if that rewrites the grub config. Don't change hd0 to hd1.

Answer (score 0):

kinda skimmed your story, but...

> The booting process was getting stuck on this message: Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360{...}-part1

there are a handful of ways to mount a file system in linux

- by-name, such as /dev/sda
- by-id, such as your problem
- by-label, having a partition label set
- *one or two others, google if interested*

mounting by-id, or by-uuid, in my opinion is preferred because it prevents a bunch of problems i won't go into explaining but is prone to failure when you forget to update the scsi-id when things change.  **A new raid controller will present a different scsi-id for the existing volume which is your problem.**

mounting `by-name` is a fail safe as long as you have just one disk, or one raid volume, present.  Then that will always be `/dev/sda#`.  So my recommendation would be to

- remove all other disks that are not the boot disk
- have only the one boot disk, or the one raid volume that is your operating system, present.  Disconnect the cables to all other disks for now
- this assumes your boot partition is on the same disk or raid volume as the operating system root partition; you can technically the boot partition on a separate disk from the root partition and you don't want to do that unless you have good reason to.
- edit your `/etc/fstab` so it only references `/dev/sda` to mount the root partition and swap.  You technically don't need to have the boot or efi partition in fstab, it is not a requirement for booting.  From your first pic you have `sdd1` for `swap` which i assume is a typo and should be `sda` ?   Because `sdd` is a different disk than `sda`.  You technically don't need to mount swap to boot and have a running system, so you can conceivably have just one `/dev/sda#  /  defaults 0 0` to mount the root partition where `#` is the correct partition number.
- SLES 11 was great in that it allowed *ELILO* rather than GRUB or GRUB2.  If you know you are using elilo, then you need to edit `elilo.conf` on the **boot partition** and not the one under `/etc/`.  In there you will see reference to calling out the boot partition by scsi-id which will be the old and incorrect one.  You can simply change it to `/dev/sda#` there provided only one disk (or raid volume) is present, where # is the correct partition number and is usually 1.  This same idea or principle applies to grub- you need to correct all the old references of disk scsi-id in grub and for now you can simply change it to `sda`.  Get the system booted, then recognize what the new scsi-id is of everything and update your elilo.conf or grub files and the `/etc/fstab`.

Consider changing `splash=silent` to `splash=verbose`.

From using the live boot cd and your pic, you already showed the correct `/dev/disk/by-id` information so you could technically type that all in, but I find it easier typing just `dev/sda#` then doing a copy and past afterwards.

in your last pic, where it says `root = /dev/disk/by-id/blabla`.  Everywhere in there it says by disk by-id change that to `/dev/sda#`.  If it had a `part1` then # = 1, `part2` is # = 2, and so on.  I don't know offhand the grub commands in sles 11 to do a proper update, rather than editing the menu.lst which says don't edit me.  You could manually edit the menu.lst on the boot partition and it will work for now, but when an update happens for a new kernel it will reference whatever global grub template (likely under /etc) and you'll have this problem all over again.  sorry i only know `grub2-mkconfig` and editing `/etc/default/grub.conf` in RHEL7; you have to find out the procedure used for grub or grub2 in sles11.

Comment: mounting by scsi id is not the same as uuid,  so your pic is close.  you can also mount by uuid, that will work in fstab and the grub files.  but for now simply use sda with just the operating system disk(s) installed, get system booted, then you can easily find the correct scsi or uuid listed under `/dev/disk/by-`

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and noob friendly response. 
sdd1 for swap was not a typo, as you can see from the picture with the old fstab, swap is assigned to a different disk.
I couldn't find elilo.conf or any mention of elilo, I looked in /boot in root and in chroot mounted in sda1 (/).

Comment: btw, don't I need to remove grub2 that I installed by mistake?

Comment: :/ tried everything you suggested but still get the same Grub error. However, now it says the error is in hd0